# How can i use multiple shapes in android xml design

Tags: android, xml

I am very new to android and trying to create a design like this in xml.[image: image description here]

I was able to create the left most portion of the design which has circle within a circle and a textview.
 [image]

Following are the files i have created for the above.

**/drawable/design_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item

    android:top="6dp"
    android:right="6dp"
    android:bottom="6dp"
    android:left="6dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#78d9ff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:width="4dp"
            android:color="#78d9ff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

**/layout/view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ec_txtDate"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/design_circle"
            android:text="09"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="50dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

But i am not able to create *** OCTOBER *** section of the design which has to adjacent to the circle. Thank you in advance.

Comment: **`layer-list`** might be what you want (i.e. layrered drawables). [Layer List](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to give clicks on each of that sub sections use the image instead.You completed the left side, when looking i think you will be expecting click on the circle so make the image into two give an image view right of the shape you created

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"//give this to align the objects in this view center alignment
        android:orientation="vertical"//remove this because it is not relevant for a relative layout but relevant for linearlayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ec_txtDate"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/design_circle"
            android:text="09"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="50dp"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/"ec_txtDate
                android:src="@drawable/your_image.png" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: It's not bout clickable, I want the different textviews i.e. day,month  to be filled dynamically.

Comment: You can do that, first create that picture without the text, and create textviews on top of that picture using relativelayout.